# How to remove the special character '^' in a python string without removing whitespace with it

Tags: python, string, dataframe, symbols

i've been wondering how to remove the special character '^' in a python string , it seems like it doesn't count like the other special characters.

I actually was trying to remove some special characters in a dataframe by using this code below :

```
def remove_special_characters(text, remove_digits=True):
    text=re.sub(r'[^a-zA-z0-9\s]+','',text)
    
    return text


df['review']=df['review'].apply(remove_special_characters)
```

but the symbol '^' is still appearing in my data , do you know some code to remove it please ?

Comment: `^` has a special meaning in that context; it doesn't match itself, instead it inverts the meaning of the character class as a whole.

Comment: In https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html, search for the string *If the first character of the set is `'^'`*

Comment: BTW, using `a-z` or `A-Z` is bad form, because whether it's correct depends on your current locale's collation order (some locales use `abc...zABC...Z`, others use `AaBbCc...Zz`, etc). Better to use predefined character classes; in PCRE you probably want `\w`.

Comment: Also, `\w` includes `\d`, and it turns out there are many many more than ten "digits" in unicode. I had some code that I thought was correct, and then `import hypothesis` quickly showed me how to break it. Live and learn!

Answer (score 1):

The use case you're tackling is already addressed
by translate(), without any need to resort to power tools
like regexes.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.maketrans

But suppose you really want to use a regex.
This unit test works fine.

```
    def test_battle(self):

        def remove(text):
            return non_alnum.sub("", text)

        non_alnum = re.compile(r"[^a-zA-Z0-9]")
        d = dict(word="Bat^tle", definition="Combat between opponents,")
        df = pd.DataFrame([d])
        self.assertEqual(["Bat^tle"], list(df.word))
        df["word"] = df.word.apply(remove)
        self.assertEqual(["Battle"], list(df.word))
```

---

Depending on specifics of your use case,
this code might be preferable:

```
        non_alnum = re.compile(r"[^\w]")  # We choose to ignore the "_" underscore detail.
        b = dict(word="Bat^tle", definition="Combat between opponents,")
        c = dict(word="Coup d'état", definition="Diplomacy through other means")
        df = pd.DataFrame([b, c])
        self.assertEqual(["Bat^tle", "Coup d'état"], list(df.word))
        df["word"] = df.word.apply(remove)
        self.assertEqual(['Battle', 'Coupdétat'], list(df.word))
```

Comment: better still would be to use the pandas string method [`pd.Series.str.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html), e.g. `df['review'].str.replace(r'[\^a-zA-z0-9\s]+', '')`

Comment: It's actually still not working. What i'm searching for , is to get rid of the character '^' in a data , for example in the string 'bat^tle' i want it to be 'battle'.